# SQL Server Service Broker "BRKR TASK" background processes strange blocking issue

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, service-broker

I have a prod server with SQL Server version: Microsoft SQL Server 2005 - 9.00.5000.00 (X64) Enterprise Edition on Windows NT 6.1 (Build 7601: Service Pack 1).

I experience a problem with Service Broker background processes "BRKR TASK" that is two (2) processes (spid 23 and 24) are blocking all other "BRKR TASK" processes and these processes have wait type LATCH_SH on resources SERVICE_BROKER_TRANSMITTER (0000000080451900) and SERVICE_BROKER_TRANSMITTER (0000000080451B10).

The strange thing is that the two blocking "BRKR TASK" processes on spids 23 and 24 are constantly changing their last_wait_type between CMEMTHREAD and PAGELATCH_EX on resource 0:0:0 (once I caught resource 2:5:32, but only once) and their wait_type is always null and wait_time is always 0.
For clarity please take a look on the screenshots: 
**[blocked spids](http://img24.imageshack.us/img24/7839/y6c.png)** and 
**[blocking spids](http://img837.imageshack.us/img837/9475/ez2n.png)**

When I try to select from sys.transmission_queue my session gets blocked on LATCH_SH on SERVICE_BROKER_TRANSMITTER (0000000080451900). My messages are not reaching the target queue so the functionality of Service Broker is corrupted.

---

The question is straightforward - what is the problem here and what could be done to solve it?

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You don't need to include signature to your posts - your user card is added automatically.

Comment: Unfortunately an issue as the one you see can only be investigated by MS customer support.